# how to add button with editable title using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple section in which the user can add multiple buttons on click, I want these buttons names to be the editable meaning user can edit and save the button title as they wish.

Here is UI how it looks when use click add button

[image]

I want a user to be able to add button title by placing a mouse on enter button name.

When a user places a mouse on enter a button name a simple pop up text area will appear something like this.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var buttonWithText = $("<div class='clickarea'>Enter button name</div>")
    $(".main-container").append(buttonWithText);
  })

})
```

```css
.main-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.clickarea {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  /* margin: 20px; */
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 80px auto;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
<button id="btn">Add button</button>
```

Comment: Please clerify "button name". Do you mean the text on the button or do you mean the name attribute of the button? Those are 2 very different things.

Comment: I mean text on the button ,

Comment: @dqhendricks are you suggesting that what I want can be accomplished just by using bootstrap modal?

Comment: All you would have to do is something like: `var buttonText = document.getElementById("buttonText").value;`. Make an input field inside your modal like `<input type="text" id="buttonText"/>` and have the user type the button text there.

Comment: okay, bro thanks, I will try that, if you wish u can add your answer, I will accept if it fits what I have asked. thx

Comment: You should accept connexo's answer as it is technically perfectly correct for your question. All I did was add the info you needed for a Bootstrap Modal after that little extra info was added through comments. That little bit of extra code isn't worth an extra answer over :)

Comment: okay, I got you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very simple solution, you can use `prompt`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    let text = prompt('enter button text:');
    var buttonWithText = $("<div class='clickarea'>"+text+"</div>")
    $(".main-container").append(buttonWithText);
  })

})
```

```css
.main-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.clickarea {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  /* margin: 20px; */
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 80px auto;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
<button id="btn">Add button</button>
```

Comment: ooh bro that was qucik , can I use bootstrap modal to your solution, I need specifically to use prompt?

Comment: I'm not a Bootstrap user, so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: @user9964622 You can use whatever you want. Basicly, on the add button click event you get the text from the textarea inside your modal and implement that the same way connexo did here.

Comment: okay, I just wanted to be more friendly user so that I can save data to json with save button

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're desired functionality is something like below. You can achieve this by taking advantage of `addEventListener` and then creating a new button and adding it to the DOM on click:

**EDIT**:

I've updated my code based on your comment. I believe it now works according to the second scenario you have described. Let me know if this does not seem like the desired functionality.

```js
function init() {
  const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#button-el');
  const buttonContainer = document.querySelector('#button-container');
  const alertButtonText = e => alert(`You clicked: ${e.target.value}`);
  const promptForText = e => {
    const text = window.prompt('Enter button text');
    if (text && text.trim().length) {
      e.target.setAttribute('value', text);
      e.target.removeEventListener('mouseover', promptForText);
      e.target.addEventListener('click', alertButtonText);
    }
  }

  buttonEl.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const newButtonEl = document.createElement('input');
    newButtonEl.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    newButtonEl.addEventListener('mouseover', promptForText);
    buttonContainer.appendChild(newButtonEl);
  });
}

init();
```

```css
#button-container>input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

body {
  background: red;
}

#button-el {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="button-el" type="button" value="Add button" />
<div id="button-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, User adds buttons and then either pop-up appears asking for button name as @connexo did, or user add button and then on placing the mouse on button title the pop up appears asking the user to enter a button name, I prefer the second solution